# Transposing 2 columns into multiple columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Using SQL Server 2008, I have one column F1 that has all the information.  Like every bunch of 7 rows makes one row.  Here is a sample:

```
F1
Header is
$760,000.00
Mar 5
Posted Jan 4
18
0
24
Like this
$849,900.00
Mar 5
Posted Jan 4
12
0
24
```

I want to transpose them to 7 columns like the following :

```
Header      Price         Valid Until   Posted On     Visit  Replies    Page No
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Header is   $760,000.00   Mar 5         Posted Jan 4    18      0       24
Like this   $849,900.00   Mar 5         Posted Jan 4    12      0       24
```

Can anyone please help with T-SQL to achieve it?

Comment: Please, read this: [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/460557)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a unique, contiguous ID of some sort to work off (starting at 1) (I've called it ID). If you don't have one you'll have to create one using row_number. Then you can do this

```
Select D1.Col as Header, D2.Col as Price, D3.Col as [Valid Until], D4.Col as [Posted On], D5.col as Visit, D6.col as Replies, D7.Col as PageNo

From dataTable D1
    inner join dataTable D2 on D2.ID = D1.ID + 1
    inner join dataTable D3 on D3.ID = D1.ID + 2
    inner join dataTable D4 on D4.ID = D1.ID + 3
    inner join dataTable D5 on D5.ID = D1.ID + 4
    inner join dataTable D6 on D6.ID = D1.ID + 5            
    inner join dataTable D7 on D7.ID = D1.ID + 6

Where D1.ID % 7 = 1  --Mod 7
```